# framebuffer not available. How to install the device /dev/fb/0 on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, framebuffer

I am trying to run an application that uses framebuffer on 2.6.31-14-generic #48-Ubuntu.

All I need to do is to install a framebuffer device to get rid of the following error:

```
/dev/fb/0: No such file or directory
framebuffer not available.
FATAL: no framebuffer available
```

I searched Google and found some resources indicating to do that on Grub2 - I got nothing though I followed them seamlessly.

Any ideas?

Comment: related: [No framebuffer device: how to enable it?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33596/1321)

Comment: related: [How do I increase console-mode resolution?](http://askubuntu.com/q/18444/3712)

Answer (score 5):

You need to activate the framebuffer drivers, which are always deactivated by default.

I configured these:

```
echo "fbcon" | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
echo "vesafb" | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

And then I commented out vesafb (this works for all cards I heard) in

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf
```

Then we update the config:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

We are almost there. Now we need to look for supported resolutions for our card in framebuffer. You probably will have to install hwinfo

```
sudo hwinfo --framebuffer
```

You can see the resolutions and its hexadecimal code.

Now you can either press the `e` key at boot time and add `vga=[hexadecimalcode]` (e.f. `vga=0x346`) or make the change permanent in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` after the `defoptions` word.

I found it more secure to try the `e` key before touching the grub configuration to be sure that it works.

Later, when you switch to `tty` with `Alt+F1-6` it will be in the resolution you specified. You can use `fbi` and other utilities.

Comment: All versions of Ubuntu after around 9.04 use Grub2.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Ubuntu had `/dev/fbX` and not `/dev/fb/X` devices?

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
$ ls -l /dev/fb/*
ls: cannot access 'fb/*': No such file or directory
$ ls -l /dev/fb*
crw-rw---- 1 root video 29, 0 авг 29 11:41 fb0
```

Try running the program with that other name, or, failing that, make a link to that file:

```
# mkdir /dev/fb
# ln /dev/fb0 /dev/fb/0
```

Running the tests:

```
# sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/fb/0
dd: writing to '/dev/fb/0': No space left on device
15001+0 records in
15000+0 records out
7680000 bytes (7,7 MB, 7,3 MiB) copied, 0,501639 s, 15,3 MB/s
# sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/fb0
dd: writing to '/dev/fb0': No space left on device
15001+0 records in
15000+0 records out
7680000 bytes (7,7 MB, 7,3 MiB) copied, 0,523867 s, 14,7 MB/s
```

It works on my box, but YMMV.