# Framebuffer device /dev/fb0 missing after installing Nvidia graphics drivers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, framebuffer

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a thin client desktop with NVIDIA ION GPU. Using the commands below, I installed NVIDIA graphic drivers while logged into the TTY1 console. After install, I rebooted.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

After installation of the NVIDIA drivers, I no longer have a framebuffer device `/dev/fb0` present. When I do `ls /dev`I do NOT see the `fb0` device listed. However, I do have the following devices listed: `nvidia0 nvidiactl nvidia-uvm`. I even tried this solution which did NOT fix the issue: https://superuser.com/a/182580/607501

This issue only happens when have the NVIDIA drivers installed. On a fresh install of Ubuntu 16 LTS, the Nouveau generic graphics drivers are active  With these drivers, `/dev/fb0` was present. The reason I need to install NVIDIA drivers are below the Nouveau drivers do NOT support HDMI connection.

The reason I need to have /dev/fb0 device present is because I want to use the [fbida (fbi)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/fbi.1.html) app, which allows me to display an image using the framebuffer in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

In [About Nvidia 340, KMS, framebuffer](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1053062-start-0.html) you can read that NVIDIA doesn't directly support frame buffers. You can emulate them installing v86d and activating the uvesafb kernel module. A more detailed HOWTO can be found in [High-resolution text console with uvesafb and Debian](https://blog.samat.org/2010/11/09/High-resolution-text-console-with-uvesafb-and-Debian/)

I wish you luck